# rock paper scissors 5 round logic

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain in only words what is wrong with my logic here and what I should try. Just steer me in the right direction. Thank you!

My problem is the game Functon logic thats confusing me... any direction would be appreciated!

```
function getComputerChoice() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  if (randomNumber === 1) {
    return "rock";
  } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
    return "paper";
  } else {
    return "scissors";
  }
}

let computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
let playerSelection = prompt("Rock? Paper? Scissors?").toLowerCase();

function playtheGame(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (computerSelection === playerSelection) {
    return "DRAW!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You win! Paper beats rock";
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You win! Scissors beats paper";
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You win! Rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "rock" && playerSelection === "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! Rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "paper" && playerSelection === "rock") {
    return "You Lose! Paper beats rock!";
  } else if (computerSelection === "scissors" && playerSelection === "paper") {
    return "You Lose! Scissors beats paper!";
  } else return "sorry lets play again...";
}

**function game**() {
  let computer = 0;
  let player = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    playtheGame();
    i++;
    if (playtheGame().includes("Lose")) {
      computer++;
    } else if (playtheGame().includes("win")) {
      player++;
    }
    if (player === 3) return "Player wins!";
    else if (computer === 3) return "Computer wins!";
  }
}
```

New updated function game code I am not sure how to start new rounds with new inputs.

```
function game() {
  let computer = 0;
  let player = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let match = playtheGame(playerSelection, computerSelection);

    if (match.includes("win")) {
      player++;
      prompt(match);
    } else if (match.includes("Lose")) {
      computer++;
      prompt(match);
    } else if (match.includes("DRAW")) {
      i--;
      prompt(match);
    }

    if (computer === 3) {
      return alert("Computer wins!");
    } else if (player === 3) {
      return alert("Player wins!");
    }
  }
}

game();
```

Comment: you are never passing any parameters to `playTheGame` so you will always end up in a draw ... Furthermore you are calling `playTheGame` multiple times for each round. You should call it only once and store the result in a variable. And finally, you are iterating `i` twice in each round, thus you will only play three rounds instead of 5 ...

Comment: You increment `i` twice. Once in the loop iterator and once inside the body of the loop.

Comment: @derpirscher can you help me with this "You should call it only once and store the result in a variable." I tried setting it to a variable but im getting a error? is that because its out of scope? let match = playTheGame(playerSelection, computerSelection);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

#1. You are calling the `playtheGame` function 3 times in every loop, meaning that every time you loop through from `i=0` to `i=5`, it checks 3 different times, what I believe it means by "call it only once and store the result in a variable" is you only call it once every time you loop and store the result. Then use the variable you stored the result in, with your if statements to check who won.

#2. You're incrementing `i` within your loop, having `i++` in the for loop automatically increments `i`, repeating `i++` means your loop is running less than 5 times.

#3. You're only getting user input as well as having the computer make a decision only once. You need to make sure you get input every time right before you check who wins, otherwise you're using the initial value that you got the very first time for all 5 games, meaning that if the player answers rock round one, the player's answer will always be rock, in fact to the player it will only appear as if the game was only one round, instead of 5.

#4. You aren't passing parameters to `playtheGame()`. It expects the player and computer selection as you defined, but since there are no parameters, it will always compare `undefined` with `undefined`, which always results in a draw.

#5. You need to make sure you don't count draws as a round, if the player draws every game the program will simply terminate without declaring a winner.

#6 (maybe). It appears you are trying to output a value to the user during `playtheGame()` and during `game()` returning does not output. So the player never sees any of the messages in `playtheGame()`. You need a `console.log()`, or an `alert()` or something of that nature to provide feedback to the user.

Also one more thing I don't see in your code but make sure you are calling `game()` somewhere.

Comment: Okay i think i solved most of the issues but am stuck on #3 . Im not sure how to get new responses recorded.  I added code to post

Comment: @appletreeisnotthereyet ask another question

Comment: @appletreeisnotthereyet Well if you want something to happen every time you put it within the loop, so each iteration of the loop you need to ask every loop.

Comment: @ArkinSolomon is there a way of making this work with ought removing the parameters of playTheGame? Or would that be the best way? If keeping the parameters how would that work? I dont understand why the parameters would mess it up.

Comment: Your parameters are fine, in fact it's good to have those parameters, but the values of the variables you are passing are not changed with every iteration of the loop. You need to make sure to reassign those variables before calling the function again, otherwise you're comparing using the same values that you used before hand.

Comment: @ArkinSolomon yeah i just cant figure it out can you help me with the answer here